# How find file name by pattern to immediately use it again for the umpteenth time

Tags: sed, command-line, grep, filesystems, find

How do we find file names by pattern to use them, for copy/move or delete etc, again for the umpteenth time in that line CLI, e.g.

```
$ ls

.hello-577
.world-999
.foo-444
jjj
hello
world
foo
kkk
lll
```

so must get all `.hello-577 .world-999 .foo-444 hello world foo` to use them in the operation said

e.g.
there's BAK directory so as if copy operation:

```
cp .hello-577 .world-999 .foo-444 hello world foo BAK
```

e.g.
they're removed so as if operating:

```
rm .hello-577 .world-999 .foo-444 hello world foo
```

Please sincere help is invaluable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cross-site posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74439788/how-find-file-name-by-pattern-to-immediately-use-it-again-for-the-umpteenth-time